# How to show $(\nabla df)(X,Y)=\nabla^2_{X,Y}f$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Why $(\nabla df)(X,Y)=\nabla^2_{X,Y}f$ ?

I only know $df(Y)=Y(f)$, I always see $df$ as an element of $T^*M$,and I think $df=f_idx^i,f_i=df(\partial_i)$.

Besides, whether $(\nabla df)(X,Y)=(\nabla_Xdf)(Y)$?

Thanks.

Comment: This is an exact duplicate since as a $(0,1)$-tensor, $\nabla F$ is $dF$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\omega=df$. Then
$(D\omega)(X,Y)=(D_X\omega)(Y)=D_X(\omega(Y))-\omega(D_X(Y))$
So if $\omega_p=0$ (i.e p is a critical point) then
$(D\omega)(X,Y)=D_X(\omega(Y))=D_X(D_Y(f))$